# Are the project beans already instantiated when we try to run a junit test in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-bean

I am new to Spring and spring boot.
For my spring boot application which is a rest controller, I have some beans along with my data source.
I use my data source to create jdbc template. Now when I am in my rest controller code, I have all these beans @Autowired and they work perfectly fine.

My query is regarding the junit testing part.
When I write my test code inside src/test/java and when I execute my test class within IDE, are the beans defined in my src/main/javacode, instantiated before test case execution?

Answer (score 1):

You might use the same container, or instantiate another container particularly for testing purposes, for which you'll provide a configuration of that other Spring Container separately:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
public class SomeClassTest{...}
```

However, you can also enable support for loading your Application Context and then use the `@Autowired` fields in your JUnit fixtures, which also works fine too:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeTestClass {
    ....
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    ....
}
```

From here, you can get any bean you wish.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. So by default they are not already instantiated. By autowiring the ApplicationContext we can use them afterwards?

Comment: There are many ways you can utilize, however, please see my updated answer.